# Erro XOOPS Strict Standards

Tags: php

XOOPS deu esse erro no *script* instalado:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method XoopsLogger::instance() should not
>   be called statically in
>   /home/b81inudo/public_html/portal/include/common.php on line 109
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method XoopsLogger::instance() should not
>   be called statically in
>   /home/b81inudo/public_html/portal/class/logger.php on line 228

---

Eu não consegui resolver, a linha de código é do `logger.php`:

```
function addBlock($name, $cached = false, $cachetime = 0) {
    if ( $this->activated )     $this->blocks[] = array('name' => $name, 'cached' => $cached, 'cachetime' => $cachetime);
}
```

E a do `common.php`:

```
if ( empty( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] ) ) {         // Not defined by IIS
    // Under some configs, IIS makes SCRIPT_NAME point to php.exe :-(
    if ( !( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] = @$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) ) {
        $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    }
    if ( isset( $_SERVER[ 'QUERY_STRING' ] ) ) {
        $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] .= '?' . $_SERVER[ 'QUERY_STRING' ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Aproveite e também diga qual a versão do php e do xoops.

Comment: Isso é conflito de versões do PHP. Você não vai resolver sem reescrever a classe XoopsLogger. Dá uma olhada [nela](http://api.xoops.org/2.5.6/d5/d63/xoopslogger_8php_source.html). Ela foi feita para o PHP 4 que foi descontinuado 7 anos atrás. Agora veja o que diz [na página de download](http://xoops.org/modules/core/) da nova versão do XOOPS: *You'll need PHP 5.3.7+* (PHP 5.3.7 ou superior requerido). E ainda assim é bem provavel que, sem ocultar os Strict Standards como eu disse o erro permaneça. Eu baixei a versão atual e ela continua escrita para PHP 4.

Comment: quando oculto os erros ele fica com a página branca.

Comment: atualizei os arquivos e ele só deu esse erro: Fatal error: Class 'XoopsPreload' not found in /home/b81inudo/public_html/portal/include/common.php on line 50

Answer (score 4):

Um método estático é definido assim:

```
class NomeDaClasse {

    public static function nomeDoMetodo( $argumento ) {}
}
```

E deve ser invocado assim:

```
NomeDaClasse::nomedoMetodo( $valorDoArgumento );
```

Em versões antigas do PHP você até poderia invocar um método de classe da forma acima mesmo que a declaração dele não tivesse a palavra-chave **static**.

Versões mais recentes passaram a caracterizar isso como erro e sempre que isso acontece um *Strict Standards* é disparado pra informar a você, programador, que o que está fazendo não faz sentido, sem um método é estático, invoque-o estaticamente. Se não é, instancie o objeto.

Muito provavelmente você está usando uma versão do XOOPS desenvolvida para versões antigas ou no mínimo não tão modernas. Ou ainda, pior, o projeto foi descontinuado e não recebe atualizações.

E você está rodando esse dinossauro numa instalação, local ou não, com uma versão do PHP superior à recomendada pelo desenvolvedor do XOOPS.

Você até pode desabilitar esse erro definindo o mais cedo, nos scripts, a seguinte instrução:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL ^ E_STRICT );
```

Mas isso é extremamente **não** recomendado!

Analisando com mais calma e a fundo, isso acaba sequer sendo conflito de versões. Eu baixei a versão atual do XOOPS (2.5.7) que diz requerer PHP 5.3.7+ e que é compatível com PHP 5.5.x.

Pode até ser, mas não seguindo as boas práticas da programação pois, analisando a classe *XoopsLogger* localizada em `/class/logger/xoopslogger.php`, ela continua escrita nos moldes do PHP 4, descontinuado **7 anos atrás**.

Veja o WordPress, por exemplo. Ele funciona perfeitamente, do jeitinho dele, mas funciona. E sofre do mesmo problema pois basta habilitar o reporte de *Strict Standards* que começa a chover erro, principalmente no *Dashboard*.

Comment: Não seria `public static function`?

Comment: Eu podia jurar que havia escrito a palavra... Obrigado!

Comment: Sem querer ser chato mais ficou `static function function` :P

Comment: Ô mais que zica. Agora arrumei.